# Python, reorganize the columns in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, group-by

I'm having a Pandas DataFrame named 'class_price_df':

```
                            email                 cat            class
0               trangthanhtin@yahoo.com     Mobiles & Tablets      1
1                    concomai@yahoo.com     Mobiles & Tablets      4
2                   yenvo.ier@gmail.com     Mobiles & Tablets      2
3                   quyenvy71@yahoo.com     Mobiles & Tablets      4
```

I'm grouping by 'email' and by 'cat' to have the max of 'class':

```
class_price_df = class_price_df.groupby(['email','cat']).max().unstack('cat').fillna(0)
```

The output is:

```
cat                               Computers & Laptops  Consumer Electronics   
email                                                                         
+coicon7879@gmail.com                               2                     0   
+haiphong82lk@yahoo.com                             0                     2   
+nguyentrungchanhbd@gmai.com                        0                     0   
-abc@gmail.com                                      0                     0   
001kukuku@gmail.com                                 0                     4
```

How can I get an output similar to:

```
                 email                 Computers & Laptops       Consumer Electronics
0      +coicon7879@gmail.com                   2                             0  
1      +haiphong82lk@yahoo.com                 0                             2 
2      +nguyentrungchanhbd@gmai.com            0                             0   
3      -abc@gmail.com                          0                             4
```

I tried

```
class_price_df.reset_index(inplace=True, level='class')
```

but the output is:

```
                            email                 class           \
cat                                       Automotive & Gadgets  Cameras   
0                +841869087649@gmail.com                     0        0   
1                  +coicon7879@gmail.com                     0        0   
2                +haiphong82lk@yahoo.com                     0        0   
3           +nguyentrungchanhbd@gmai.com                     0        0
```

Comment: Surely you want `class_price_df.reset_index(inplace=True, level='email')`?

Comment: just do `class_price_df.reset_index()`, you only have one level, no need to specify